# Can't build a simple Yesod project using stack, getting an error with language-javascript-0.7.1.0 package

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-stack

I am trying to build a simple Yesod project, but after `stack build` command I get the next error

```
#24 532.1 --  While building package language-javascript-0.7.1.0 (scroll up to its section to see the error) using:
#24 532.1       /root/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_3.0.1.0_ghc-8.8.4 --verbose=1 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-3.0.1.0 build --ghc-options ""
#24 532.1     Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

How can I fix it?

Edit: The error with the package is the next one    `hGetContents: invalid argument (invalid byte sequence)`

Comment: It might be a good idea to "`scroll up to its section to see the error`" and add that to your question.

Comment: @Noughtmare thank you, I have added it to the question

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70803989/7203016).